# Merge Data onto a single row per record - Possible PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data that I'm trying to organise from an older system. It lists our emails and numbers on seperate rows within the database.

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( [LookupCode] char(10), [Title] varchar(20), [FirstName] varchar(30), [MiddleName] varchar(16), [LastName] varchar(30), [Number] varchar(150), [EmailWeb] varchar(150), [TypeCode] char(3), [Primary] int )
INSERT INTO #temptable ([LookupCode], [Title], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName], [Number], [EmailWeb], [TypeCode], [Primary])
VALUES
( 'ANDERSSO01', 'Miss', 'Jessie', '', 'Bloggs', '', 'abc@gmail.com', 'EM1', 1 ), 
( 'ANDERSSO01', 'Mr', 'Joe', '', 'Bloggs', '01363936541', '', 'RES', 0 ), 
( 'ANDERSSO01', 'Mr', 'Joe', '', 'Bloggs', '', 'xyz@gmail.com', 'EM1', 0 ), 
( 'ANDERSSO01', 'Miss', 'Jessie', '', 'Bloggs', '073321663', '', 'RES', 1 )

SELECT * FROM #temptable t

DROP TABLE #temptable
```

This basically returns the data as the following SQL Fiddle shows:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b475b/1

[image]

I have managed to get a result by initially doing subqueries - however these fall over for this example because there are multiple contacts for the same LookupCode, the subqueries only worked for one record.

Ultimately there should only be two rows - one for Jessie and one for Joe with both the number and email on the same line.

`WHERE TypeCode = 'EM1'`

is for an email and RES is for a Home tel - I have removed the ACT TypeCode as its erroneous.

Assistance would be appreciated I've tried using a PIVOT but with mixed results - an UNPIVOT doesn't work for the data is already in an UNPIVOT format essentially based on what TypeCode is filtered on.

**UPDATE - PIVOT EXAMPLE **

```
WITH
    cte
AS  (
        SELECT
                c.LookupCode
            , cn.LkPrefix 'Title'
            , cn.FirstName
            , cn.MiddleName
            , cn.LastName
              , CAST(cn2.Number AS VARCHAR(150)) 'Number'
              , CAST(cn2.EmailWeb AS VARCHAR(150)) 'EmailWeb'
              , cn2.TypeCode
              , cn2.TypeCode 'TypeCode2'
              , c.UniqEntity
              , cn2.UniqContactName
              , IIF(c.UniqContactNamePrimary = cn2.UniqContactName, 1, 0) "Primary"
        FROM
                dbo.Client        c
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.ContactNumber cn2           
                    ON cn2.UniqEntity = c.UniqEntity --AND cn2.UniqContactName = c.UniqContactNamePrimary
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ContactName cn ON c.UniqEntity = cn.UniqEntity AND cn2.UniqContactName = cn.UniqContactName
        WHERE
                c.LookupCode = @LookupCode
    )
    select RES 'Home', MOB 'Mobile',  EM1 'Email', [Primary], FirstName, LastName
from
(
  select *
  from cte
) d
pivot
(
  max(Number)
  for TypeCode in (RES, MOB)
) piv
pivot
(
  max(EmailWeb)
  for TypeCode2 in (EM1)
) piv2
```

Result

[image]

Comment: What was your actually attempt using `PIVOT`, as that seems to be what you need (or conditional aggregation).

Comment: You say you cannot use subqueries because some contacts have more than one record. But when a contact has two phone number and you want to show both in one line, which one do you show? For example, ANDERSSO01 has 073321663 and 01363936541. Do you want to show both in the same line (also with the email in that line)?

Comment: @Larnu I have placed my full PIVOT attempt above, and the result.

Comment: @Carlos everything should be grouped as per the first name and last name and the email and number should be on the same line together with the name.

Comment: I suggest your schema is very flawed and that is the reason you struggle. You did not specify any constraints in your table so there is no primary key nor natural (unique) key(s). You have repeating values, null values and empty strings scattered through what seem to be related rows. TypeCode seems to be important but its function is not clear. I suggest you revisit the decisions that resulted in this table. A poorly designed schema will require more work and complexity to retrieve useful and accurate information.

Comment: @SMor I haven't designed this - this is a policy admin system db and nothing to do with me - I've made that clear at the start of the post.

Comment: There is no way to correlate the rows together, there is no common join or partitioning column. Remember that tables have no inherent ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would, personally, use conditional aggregation here. You don't explain what you want to do with the `TypeCode` and `Primary` values so i have omitted them, however, if you do want them in the query they will need to be aggregated in some way, not added to the `GROUP BY` (adding them to the `GROUP BY` will cause multiple rows):

```sql
SELECT t.LookupCode,
       t.Title,
       t.FirstName,
       t.LastName,
       MAX(t.Number) AS Number,
       MAX(t.EmailWeb) AS EmailWeb
FROM #temptable t
GROUP BY t.LookupCode,
         t.Title,
         t.FirstName,
         t.LastName;
```

Comment: That's not going to work, given the `NULL` rows, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8351de211f3adbb334e30755783ddbe1. There is just no way of correlating these rows together

Comment: I'm basing this on the sample DDL and DML the OP has given us, @Charlieface, and there are no `NULL` rows. I can't cater for scenarios the OP doesn't define.

Comment: @Larnu - Exactly what i've just been and done myself - I figured I had looked at this that long I had missed the point. Took a step away for an hour and did exactly that -  GROUPED on a UniqueContactName ID. As you said Conditional Aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

I gave this a try, maybe I have missed something but I did not see the need to PIVOT

```
    with data (LookupCode, Title, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Num, EmailWeb, 
    
        TypeCode, Primary)as (
        select 

 'ANDERSSO01', 'Miss', 'Jessie', '', 'Bloggs', '', 'abc@gmail.com', 'EM1', 1 from dual union all 
    select  'ANDERSSO01', 'Mr', 'Joe', '', 'Bloggs', '01363936541', '', 'RES', 0 from dual union all
    select  'ANDERSSO01', 'Mr', 'Joe', '', 'Bloggs', '', 'xyz@gmail.com', 'EM1', 0 from dual union all
    select  'ANDERSSO01', 'Miss', 'Jessie', '', 'Bloggs', '073321663', '', 'RES', 1 from dual 
    )
    select d1.LookupCode
    , d1.Title
    , d1.FirstName
    , d1.MiddleName
    , d1.LastName
    , (select Num from data d2 where d1.LookupCode = d2.LookupCode
    and d1.Title = d2.Title
    and d1.FirstName = d2.FirstName
    and d2.TypeCode != 'EM1') num2
    , d1.EmailWeb
    , d1.TypeCode
    , d1.Primary 
    from data d1
    where d1.TypeCode = 'EM1'
```